# Get page permalink and title outside the loop in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, function, loops, title

How to Get page permalink and title outside the loop in wordpress.

I have a function like

```
function get_post_info(){
  $post;
  $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
  return $post_info('url' => $permalink, 'title' => $title);
}
```

when this function called within the loop, it returns the post's title and url.

When it is called outside the loop. It is not returning the current page's title and url. When called in home page it should return the home page's title and url

How to get like this ? instead this function returns the latest posts title and url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research i found the ans myself

`wp_title()` will return the page title and

`$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to return the page url

Answer (score 2):

You're opening yourself up to a possible [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack by printing an unescaped `REQUEST_URI`.

Your function is fine, you're just missing the `global` keyword. Change `$post;` to `global $post;`, and you're sailing!

Comment: Is there any problem with the super global variables? those are unsafe ? please explain me because, i am developing a plugin and these are used that plugin

Comment: This isn't really something I can cover in a comment - Google 'PHP security', read about XSS, and always sanitize and escape data from sources that the end user can manipulate.